# Access VBA - Error 424 Object Required when creating word template

Tags: vba, ms-access

what I'm trying to do is open a word template from Access, populate some information and then attach it to an email. This is working fine in Office 2019 but our work computers are running office 2010 and it seems that after every two/three attempts, it fails with Object Required error. It's this line that's failing:

> Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("F:\whatever.dotx")

oWord definitely contains the Word application when it's failing so I don't really understand why it's doing it after 3/4 attempts.

```
Private Sub Command154_Click()

Dim RecordID As Integer, OrgName As String, RecordComment As Variant, ContactName As String, ContactEmail As String, CName As Variant, ContractEndD As Variant
Dim ContactFirst1, ContactFirst, oWordTbl As Object, newrow As Integer, rowNew As Object, i As Integer, wdDoNotSaveChanges, myAttachments, ContractEnd, newfilename As String

OrgName = Me.OrganisationName
ContactName = Me.ContactName
ContactEmail = Me.Email_1
CName = Me.CName1
RecordID = Me.CommID
RecordComment = ContactName & " - " & ContactEmail
ContractEndD = Me.ContractEndDate
If IsNull(ContractEndD) Then ContractEndD = "<span style='background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow'>[DD/MM/YYYY]</span>"

If Not IsNull(ContactName) Then
ContactFirst1 = Split(ContactName)
ContactFirst = ContactFirst1(0)
End If

Dim oWord As Object, iRecCount As Integer, iFldCount As Integer, j As Integer

 Set oWord = CreateWord
       oWord.Visible = True

       Dim oDoc As Object

  Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("F:\whatever.dotx")


    Dim cnStr As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cnRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

cnRs.Open "SELECT CName1, CEmail1,TypeOfContact FROM Comms WHERE ContactID = " & Me.ContactID & ";", cn, adOpenKeyset

    With cnRs
If .RecordCount <> 0 Then
            .MoveLast   'Ensure proper count
            iRecCount = .RecordCount    'Number of records returned by the table/query
            .MoveFirst
            iFldCount = .Fields.Count   'Number of fields/columns returned by the table/query
    End If

    Debug.Print iRecCount

     Set oWordTbl = oDoc.Tables(1)

For newrow = 1 To iRecCount
Set rowNew = oWordTbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=oWordTbl.Rows(3))
Next newrow

            'Build our data rows
            For i = 1 To iRecCount
               oWordTbl.Cell(i + 2, 2) = Nz(cnRs![CName1], "")
            oWordTbl.Cell(i + 2, 3) = Nz(cnRs![CEmail1], "")
            oWordTbl.Cell(i + 2, 4) = Nz(cnRs![TypeOfContact], "")
                .MoveNext
            Next i


    End With
    With oDoc
        .SaveAs "H:\whatever.docx"
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges            
    End With

If oWord.Documents.Count = 0 Then oWord.Quit

'----------------------------

Dim objOutlook As Object, objEmail As Object, EmailTemplate As String
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
EmailTemplate = "F:\whatever.oft"
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(EmailTemplate)
With objEmail
 Set myAttachments = .Attachments
 myAttachments.Remove 1
         myAttachments.Add "H:\whatever.docx"

    .To = Nz(ContactEmail)
    .Display
End With

newfilename = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss") & " - " & OrgName & ".docx"

Name "H:\whatever.docx" As "H:\whatever\" & newfilename
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objEmail = Nothing

Set oWord = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing

  End Sub

Private Function CreateWord(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTempWD As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTempWD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTempWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    oTempWD.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateWord = oTempWD

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateWord."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Check in Tools -> References. 
It's probably that, on change the computer, you've reference to wrong Microsoft Word Class.

If so, there are many routines for adding the right reference

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if it was a reference issue. But surely it would be failing every time and not just every 2 or 3 times.

Comment: It is really a strange problem, but we will try to help:
I would think that the error could be that you don't close the connections and the objects once used.

Try to close connection, oword y odoc before terminate

conn.close
set conn=nothing

Comment: I tried closing it but it's the same error.

Comment: If so, I would need to view the work in a reduced format, in order to analyze it. What I don't know is if StackOverFlow policy allows it

Answer (score 0):

I did actually solve this issue. The problem was putting the link to the template inside the oWord.Documents.Add(). When I put the template inside of a variable first, then called the variable in the function, it worked fine.

```
Dim strFilename As String
   strFilename = "F:\whatever.dotx"
  Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(strFilename)
```